# Role Hierarchy...Kinda

Tags: php, database-design, architecture, authorization

I have the table structure below

Here are the tables.

```
Users:
  + userid
  + roleid /* Associate a Role to a User */

Roles:
  + roleid
  + rolename

Permissions:
  + permissionid
  + permissionname

RolePermissions:
  + roleid
  + permissionid /* Associate a Permission to a Role */
```

Hoping the structure makes sense.

I need users with the `change_password` permission to be able to change a user's password. Which is simple just assign the permission to their role.

The complication is that certain roles can only change certain types of users' passwords. e.g A Janitor can change a Junior Janitors Password But not a Teacher's Password. So can't just do a `$user->can('edit_password')` check. Also don't want a bunch of `if_this_role_is_editing_this_role` checks. Is there a really nice way you guys would approach this? Thanks.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
**SO is not** a free Coding service ___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Comment: Hey @RiggsFolly this is not so much a code question, more of an architecture question. Hence the lack of code. Thanks.

Comment: Then its even more Off Topic then

Comment: @RiggsFolly Apologies wasn't aware that was frowned upon. I'll read the guides.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "power" col to your user table. That way, you can block an action if the user is doing an action on a user that has a power bigger or equal to his own power privileges.